# My car is not starting will only start with a jump

Tags: starting

I have a 2001 Nissan Quest and it will only start by using jumper cables.I have gotten a new battery for it and replaced the alternator but still it will only start with a jump.when trying to start it it does make a sound like it is trying to start but it can’t.can anyone help me figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you take a look around on the site, you'll probably see a half dozen other people (and I'm betting that number is on the low side) who've experienced the same issue as you are right now. If you take a look, many people's issue with this is, there's a connection problem between the battery and the cables, either through the clamp or cable and starter or ground. You might want to start there by cleaning all of the connections and seeing if it helps.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a jump?  Do you mean using jump leads to another car’s battery, or putting the battery on a charger while trying to start the car?